# Ajax stopped working in Chrome after switching to Lighttpd

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, lighttpd

I am having problem with rendering text/json in Chrome. I use YUI library to send ajax request and process response.

The problem appeared right after I switched from Apache with mod_php to Lighttpd with php-fpm as fastcgi. Ajax requests something from the server, server returns content of type text/json (declared content text/json in header)

Works and renders in all browsers Except for Chrome. That's what's so strange about it is that it works in Firefox, Safari, IE but not in Chrome.

I have no idea what's going on here. I even disable output compression because I though it was causing the problem, but the problem still did not go away.

I hope someone has alreade been through this problem and figured out how to fix it.

Comment: First thing I would do is use TamperData with Firefox to make absolutely sure that the response headers look correct.

Comment: Try using Fiddler to check the response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty unbeleivable but I traced it down to this:
On the server side, using php I was setting the header just before sending the output, like this:
header("Content-type: text/json; charset=UTF-8");

It was working just fine for all browsers, except for Chrome, which expected the Content-Type 
notice the upper case "T"
So after I changed it to this:
header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=UTF-8");

everything works in Chrome too.
Why was it working with Apache/mod_php and stopped working with Lighttpd/fastcgi? I guess
Apache was somehow fixing all the headers just before there were actually sent out and Lighttpd does not really care.

I am surprised I was even able to track this down.

I hope I earn a badge for solving my own question and hopefully it will help someone else who may be having the same problem.

Comment: Excellent heads-up. I just checked all my scripts and luckily, the capital T was everywhere.